# What is the equivalent of bigint in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, bigint

What am I supposed to use when handling a value in C#, which is bigint for an SQL Server database?

Answer (score 453, accepted):

That corresponds to the **long** (or **Int64**), a 64-bit integer.

Although if the number from the database happens to be small enough, and you accidentally use an Int32, etc., you'll be fine. But the **Int64** will definitely hold it.

And the error you get if you use something smaller and the full size is needed? **A stack overflow!** Yay!

Comment: Sure it's not integer overflow?

Comment: Good reference for more data types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx

Comment: in C#, `long` is not capitalized.

Answer (score 81):

`Int64` maps directly to `BigInt`.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.aspx)

Comment: is long other name for Int64 /

Comment: Yes. The `long` keyword is an alias for `System.Int64`.

Answer (score 14):

I just had a script that returned the primary key of an insert and used a

```sql
SELECT @@identity
```

on my bigint primary key, and I get a cast error using long - that was why I started this search. The correct answer, at least in my case, is that the type returned by that select is NUMERIC which equates to a decimal type. Using a long will cause a cast exception.

This is one reason to check your answers in more than one Google search (or even on Stack Overflow!).

To quote a database administrator who helped me out:

> ... BigInt is not the same as INT64 no matter how much they look alike. Part of the reason is that SQL will frequently convert Int/BigInt to Numeric as part of the normal processing. So when it goes to OLE or .NET the required conversion is NUMERIC to INT. 
>
> We don't often notice since the printed value looks the same.

Comment: Thanks for the numeric tip.. just helped me out big time!

Comment: You got a cast error because SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY return NUMERIC(38, 0), not because your BigInt PK does not fit into a C# Int64.  In other words, BigInt _is_ the same as Int64, but BigInt values returned through SCOPE_IDENTITY or @@IDENTITY may be up-converted to NUMERIC(38, 0).

Comment: Thanks Dan.  FYI, still happening with SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 & .NET v 4.5

Comment: Surprised to see no comment to Dan's correction about the type for SQL Server identity values to just use the following on the DB side: SELECT CAST(@@IDENTITY as BIGINT) as IdentityINT64

Answer (score 9):

Use a long datatype.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `long` type or `Int64`

Answer (score 4):

I think the equivalent is Int64

Answer (score 2):

**int** in sql maps directly to **int32** also know as a primitive type i.e *int* in *C#* whereas

**bigint** in Sql Server maps directly to **int64** also know as a primitive type i.e *long* in *C#*

An explicit conversion if biginteger to integer has been defined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268292(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

I managed to convert the (bigint) value returned from the DB using Convert.ToInt64.

ie

```
var Id = Convert.ToInt64(identityAsTable.Rows[0].Field<object>(0));
```

Answer (score -2):

For most of the cases it is long(int64) in c#

Comment: This seems to be just a repeat of the existing answers.

Answer (score -3):

if you are using **bigint** in your database table, you can use **Long** in C#

Comment: This seems to be just a repeat of the existing answers.

Answer (score -3):

int(64) or long Datatype is equivalent to BigInt.

Comment: This seems to be just a repeat of the existing answers.

Answer (score -6):

I was handling a bigint datatype to be shown in a DataGridView and made it like this

```
something = (int)(Int64)data_reader[0];
```