# Unnecessary conversion to bigint

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, expression

I have employee table with `bigint` primary key field in database and entity data model with database first approach. Employee class have this structure

```
public partial class Employee
{
     public long Emp_No { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Family { get; set; }
     ...
}
```

I write this basic query with Entity Framework

```
List<long> ids = new List<long>() {1,2,3,4,5,6}
database.Employees.Where(q => ids.Contain(q.Emp_No)).ToList();
```

It Generate query as the following:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Emp_No] AS [Emp_No], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Family] AS [Family], 
    ...
    FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Emp_No] IN (cast(0 as bigint), 
                                 cast(1 as bigint), 
                                 cast(2 as bigint), 
                                 cast(3 as bigint), 
                                 cast(4 as bigint), 
                                 cast(5 as bigint), 
                                 cast(6 as bigint))
```

As you can see there is unnecessary cast to bigint in query while both type of `Emp_No` and `ids` array are `long`, It causes bad execution times specially whenever `ids` array has many elements.

How can I remove this redundant cast?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is virtually no cost in the conversion `cast(0 as bigint)` and because `Emp_No` is also a `bigint` if you did not have the cast there the int would still need to be promoted to a bigint to be able to do the `IN` comparision so the cast would still happen, just behind the scenes.

Run the non cast version of the query yourself in management studio and get the actual execution plan and you will still see the conversion in the query plan.

Answer (score -2):

Not really sure what you're asking for here but..

Change your long to int and the query should make you an int instead of bigint.

```
public partial class Employee
 {
     public int Emp_No { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Family { get; set; }
     ....
 }
```

Long is the equivalent of bigint. 
You can read more here: [What is the equivalent of bigint in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113526/what-is-the-equivalent-of-bigint-in-c)

Comment: I can't do this.. I need long type